# Storyboard compilation failed when identifier of prototype cell is set

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am stuck at a problem where whenever I set the identifier of the prototype cell in my TableView, Storyboard fails to compile. I think I have done everything right, extended `UITableViewCell` and created IBOutlets in that class, created a DataSource and Delegate for my TableView and implemented necessary methods, and everything.

My cell has 4 UIImages, some 8 UILabels and 1 UIButton. When I delete them all, the storyboard compiles with the identifier. But it doesn’t it those components present. Surprisingly, it compiles for two UIImages out of those four, and doesn’t compile for anything else. Also, it doesn’t fail if I remove all the UI items that I have created IBOutlets for. Once they’ve all been removed, things that don’t have IBOutlets show up in the table, but the execution does not go inside the `VenueCardCell` class.

I’ve noticed that the failure doesn’t depend on the existence of my `VenueCardCell` class. It fails even if the class doesn’t exist.

In all the cases, everything compiles when I don't set an identifier for prototype cell. But then  nothing shows up in the table. In fact even when it compiles, nothing shows up in the table.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Please help! Let me know if you need to see anything else here.

This is my class that extends `UITableViewCell`

```
@interface VenueCardCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *vImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *favoriteButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *vnLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *vaLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *vdLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *waitLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rwaitLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ratioLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fLabel;

@end

@implementation VenueCardCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

And this is my ViewController Class — (for simplicity, I have hardcoded some values so I can only see the same cell 10 times)

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"VenueCard";

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 10;
    return numberOfRows;
}

- (VenueCardCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView registerClass:[VenueCardCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    VenueCardCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. A few hours ago when I created the ViewController, I had added IBOutlets from the Cell to the ViewController. Of course, this wouldn’t have worked, so I deleted the outlets from the class, thinking that Xcode will automatically delete the references in the storyboard. Unfortunately that doesn’t happen. And I spent the whole night figuring out what was wrong. After removing those references, everything is working fine. And now I am feeling stupid.